# how to get special character from string in nodejs and replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

how to find specific special character from string and replace it to unicode \u0026  + = \u002B

replace only these special character : [$, &, +, #]

example : "HELLO JAMES (WITH ME YOUR) \n+++ SEE & FIELD 4-B +++

MY code

```
 var char = '+';      
          var saa =char.charCodeAt(0);
          console.log(saa)
          var codeHex = saa.toString(16).toUpperCase();
          while (codeHex.length < 4) {
            codeHex = "0" + codeHex;
        }    
        var afteruni = name.replaceAll('\+','\\u'+codeHex) 

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

i want like this :

> "HELLO JAMES (WITH ME YOUR) \n\u002B\u002B\u002B SEE \u0026 FIELD 4-B
> \u002B\u002B\u002B"

ERROR : Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to redefined `replaceAll` - why do that? `replaceAll` will already give you a correct response :

just replace line: `var afteruni = name.replaceAll('\+','\\u'+codeHex)`

with `var afteruni = name.replaceAll(/\+/g,'\\u'+codeHex)`

iv'e run that in my PC and it is working.